# Load all lazy collection at once with hibernate/spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem that loading my lazy collections produces a lot of SQL-Statements and I wonder if there is no more efficient way of loading the data.

**Situation:**

*Parent* has a lazy collection of *Child* called children. It is actually a Many-To-Many relation.

I load a list of *Parent*s with a CrudRepository and I need to get all child_ids for each *Parent*. So every time I access the children collection i executes a new SQL-Statement.

If i load 200 *Parents* there are 201 queries executes (1 for the list of Parents and 1 for each Parent's children).

Any idea how i can load the data with just one query?

**EDIT 1**

Parent/Child is probably a bad naming here. In fact i have a Many-To-Many relation.

Here is some code:

```
@Entity
public class Tour {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",
        strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="parent_images",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tour_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TOUR_IMAGE_TOUR"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TOUR_IMAGE_IMAGE")
    )
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid",
        strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String id;

    //....
}

// Code to fetch:
@Autowired
TourRepository repo;
List<Tour> tours = repo.findBy(....);


List<String> imageIds = new ArrayList<>();

for(Tour tour : tours){
    imageIds.addAll(tour.getImages().stream().map(b -> b.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: If you only need parents with all children IDs for each parent, why not just use JDBC-based DAO (using `JdbcTemplate`, for example) for this method and write a simple sql like `select parent_id, child_id from parents, childs join ...`?

Comment: Show your code pls.. entities, repos, usage example with the bad result...

Comment: When we talk about Parent-Child, it is supposed to be One-To-Many..

Comment: Actually i want to use the convenient method of spring-data/jpa/hibernate to handle all the SQL-stuff.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer suggested, `JOIN FETCH` is usually the way to solve similar problem.  What happens internally for join-fetch is that the generated SQL will contains columns of the join-fetched entities.

However, you shouldn't blindly treat join-fetch being the panacea.

One common case is you want to retrieve entities with 2 One-To-Many relationships.  For example, you have `User`, and each `User` may have multiple `Address` and `Phone`

If you naively do a `from User user join fetch user.phones join fetch users.addresses`, Hibernate will either report problem in your query, or generate a inefficient query which contains Cartesian product of addresses and phones.

In the above case, one solution is to break it into multiple queries:
`from User user join fetch user.phones where ....` followed by `from User user join fetch user.addresses where ....`.

Keep in mind: less number of SQL does not always means better performance.  In some situation, breaking up queries may improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

That's the whole idea behind lazy collections :)

Meaning, a lazy collection will only be queried if the getter for that collection is called, what you're saying is that you load all entities and something (code, framework, whatever) calls the `getChildren` (assumption) for that entity; This will produce those queries.

<strike>Now, if this is always happening, then first of all, there's no point in having a lazy collection, set them as `EAGER`.</strike> - EDIT: as said in the comments, EAGER is rarely the solution, in this case in particular it definitely does not seem like it, the join is though :)

Either way, for your case that won't help, what you want is to load all data at once I assume, for that, when you do the query you have to make the join explicit, example with JPQL:

```
SELECT p FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.children
```

Comment: Using EAGER is rarely a correct solution.  There are too many situation that it will still generate n+1 queries.  I would rather suggest doing join fetch etc

Comment: NEVER is a strong word :) But yes, in this case it most likely is not. Will edit the answer

Comment: eheheheh :) fair enough :)